# Adding together GetCount Results

Tags: arcpy, count

Is there anyway to add together `GetCount` Results? I am using `GetCount` to find the number of selected features for multiple layers but when I try to add them all together I get an error message saying `it is an unsupported operand type for +: 'Result' and 'Result'.`

```
SampledFaild = arcpy.GetCount_management('SamplingFaild')
SampledValid = arcpy.GetCount_management('SamplingValid')
Total = SampledFaild + SampledValid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the return value of `GetCount_management` is a [Result](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm) object. The [documentation for GetCount](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm) includes an example of how to extract the return value, by casting the `Result.GetOutput()` value to integer.

Rewriting your code to use [Style Guide for Python (PEP 8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommended leading lowercase variable names, the result is:

```py
sampledFaild = arcpy.GetCount_management('SamplingFaild')
sampledValid = arcpy.GetCount_management('SamplingValid')
total = int(sampleFaild.getOutput(0)) + int(sampleValid.getOutput(0))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: While it might seem bit rude, please do not leave thank you comments, because, as the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) Help document explains, it's really not necessary.